# re.match vs re.search performance difference

Tags: python, regex

I tried to compare `re.match` and `re.search` using `timeit` module and I found that match was better than search when the string I want to found was at the beginning of the string.

```
>>> s1 = '''
... import re
... re.search(r'hello','helloab'*100000)
... '''
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s1,number=10000)
32.12064480781555


>>> s = '''
... import re
... re.match(r'hello','helloab'*100000)
... '''
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s,number=10000)
30.9136700630188
```

Now, I am aware that match looks for the pattern in the beginning of the string and return an object if found but what I am wondering is how does search operate.

Does search performs any extra matching after the string is found in the beginning which slows it down?

**Update**

After using @David Robinsons code I got results simlar to him.

```
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.match('hello')",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('hello')",
...              number = 10000000)
49.9567620754
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.search('hello')",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('hello')",
...             number = 10000000)
35.6694438457
```

So, the updated question is now why `search` is out-performing `match`?

Comment: You really should construct the test string and the regex object in the `setup` parameter to `timeit` so that you are only measuring the match/search itself. And do a lot more than 10 iterations.

Comment: @interjay: Increased it to `10000`. Tried `number=100000` but on my netbook it was taking way too much time.

Comment: ...but you didn't do the other things I said, so you aren't measuring anything significant to your question (most of the time is spent constructing the string).

Comment: @interjay: Actually this is the first time I have used `timeit`. So, currently reading the docs on how to move import and string construction out of setup.

Comment: @Noob: See my answer for an example (might be worth running my code on your machine)

Comment: What about searching pattern? I suppose, a target pattern could also affect on performance of operations. In case of simple 'hello' string  `s.find('hello')` is the fastest way for searching. At my machine it takes 1.99 seconds(re.search: 14.0, re.match: 16.7).

Answer (score 20):

> *"So, the updated question is now why search is out-performing match?"*

In this particular instance where a literal string is used rather than a regex pattern, indeed `re.search` is slightly faster than `re.match` for the default CPython implementation (I have not tested this in other incarnations of Python).

```
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.match(s)",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('hello')",
...              number = 10000000)
3.29107403755
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.search(s)",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('hello')",
...             number = 10000000)
2.39184308052
```

Looking into the [C code behind those modules](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0ee03c9b098f/Modules/_sre.c), it appears the search code has a built in optimisation [to quickly match patterns prefixed with a string lateral](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0ee03c9b098f/Modules/_sre.c#l1506). In the example above, the whole pattern is a literal string with no regex patterns and so this optimised routined is used to match the whole pattern.

Notice how the performance degrades once we introduce regex symbols and, as the literal string prefix gets shorter:

```
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.search(s)",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('hell.')",
...             number = 10000000)

3.20765399933
>>> 
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.search(s)",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('hel.o')",
...             number = 10000000)
3.31512498856
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.search(s)",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('he.lo')",
...             number = 10000000)
3.31983995438
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.search(s)",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('h.llo')",
...             number = 10000000)
3.39261603355
```

For portion of the pattern that contain regex patterns, [SRE_MATCH](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0ee03c9b098f/Modules/_sre.c#l776) is used to determine matches. That is essentially the same code behind `re.match`.

Note how the results are close (with `re.match` marginally faster) if the pattern starts with a regex pattern instead of a literal string.

```
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.match(s)",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('.ello')",
...              number = 10000000)
3.22782492638
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.search(s)",
...              setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('.ello')",
...             number = 10000000)
3.31773591042
```

---

In other words, ignoring the fact that `search` and `match` have different purposes, `re.search` is faster than `re.match` only when the pattern is a literal string.

Of course, if you're working with literal strings, you're likely to be better off using string operations instead.

```
>>> # Detecting exact matches
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="s == r", 
...              setup="s = 'helloab'*100000; r = 'hello'", 
...              number = 10000000)
0.339027881622

>>> # Determine if string contains another string
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="s in r", 
...              setup="s = 'helloab'*100000; r = 'hello'", 
...              number = 10000000)
0.479326963425


>>> # detecting prefix
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="s.startswith(r)",
...              setup="s = 'helloab'*100000; r = 'hello'",
...             number = 10000000)
1.49393510818
>>> print timeit.timeit(stmt="s[:len(r)] == r",
...              setup="s = 'helloab'*100000; r = 'hello'",
...             number = 10000000)
1.21005606651
```

Comment: Fantastic research and experimentation. Thank you especially for including links to the source.

Answer (score 7):

On my machine (Python 2.7.3 on Mac OS 10.7.3, 1.7 GHz Intel Core i5), when done putting the string construction, importing re, and the regex compiling in setup, and performing 10000000 iterations instead of 10, I find the opposite:

```
import timeit

print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.match(s)",
             setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('hello')",
             number = 10000000)
# 6.43165612221
print timeit.timeit(stmt="r.search(s)",
             setup="import re; s = 'helloab'*100000; r = re.compile('hello')",
            number = 10000000)
# 3.85176897049
```

Comment: I confirm this result. (OS X 10.5.8, python 2.7.3)  I get that `search` is approximately 25% faster.

Comment: As noted in edit, I find the gap increases if the regex compiling is done in the setup statement.

Comment: I have similar results at my Linux box(Archlinux, python 2.7.3), but why search is faster than match? Interesting that python 3.2.3 executes the same tests about 40.8 and 37.3 seconds(python 2.7 -> 16.7 and 14.0) at by box, it's about 2.5 times slower!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `r.match(s)` and `r.search(s)`? (not that it would make much difference to performance in this case since the matching string appears right at the beginning).

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Got results similar to yours i,e `search` out-performs `match`. Any idea why?

Comment: @ShawnChin: You're absolutely right, fixed (times were slightly different, though not qualitatively so, so I posted them as well.

Comment: @Noob: Not yet. Still considering.

Comment: @dr.: Also interested in your results about python 2.7 and python 3.xx

Comment: @Noob: When I run this with Python3 (changing the print statements to the new syntax), I get times like 5.34 and 3.94 (respectively). It looks like the `match` call has sped up a bit but is still slower.