# Why use re.match(), when re.search() can do the same thing?

Tags: python, regex

From the documentation, it's very clear that:

- `match()` -> apply pattern match at the beginning of the string
- `search()` -> search through the string and return first match

And `search` with `'^'` and without `re.M` flag would work the same as `match`.

Then why does python have `match()`? Isn't it redundant?
Are there any performance benefits to keeping `match()` in python?

Comment: It's a convenience for a common pattern, and it makes the intent clearer.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803709/re-match-vs-re-search-performance-difference) for performance benchmarks. `re.search` can actually be faster at times.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Comment: Zen of Python: "There should be one — and preferably only one — obvious way to do it.". This obviously violates that.

Comment: @karthikmanchala this question doen't ask what's the difference but "who the heck done it and why?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Why" questions are hard to answer. As a matter of fact, you could define the function  `re.match()` like this:

```
def match(pattern, string, flags):
    return re.search(r"\A(?:" + pattern + ")", string, flags)
```

(because `\A` always matches at the start of the string, regardless of the `re.M` flag status´).

So `re.match` is a useful shortcut but not strictly necessary. It's especially confusing for Java programmers who have `Pattern.matches()` which anchors the search to the start *and end*  of the string (which is probably a more common use case than just anchoring to the start).

It's different for the `match` and `search` methods of regex *objects*, though, as Eric has pointed out.

Comment: _"you could define the function"_ No you can't. This match gives a different result when used with the `pos` argument (assuming you forwarded it where necesary)

Comment: @Eric: The module-level *functions* don't have a `pos` argument. Only the regex object's methods do (which is why I mentioned your answer in the last line).

Answer (score 11):

The `pos` argument behaves differently in important ways:

```
>>> s = "a ab abc abcd"
>>> re.compile('a').match(s, pos=2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='a'>
>>> re.compile('^a').search(s, pos=2)
None
```

`match` makes it possible to write a tokenizer, and ensure that characters are never skipped. `search` has no way of saying "start from the earliest allowable character".

Example use of match to break up a string with no gaps:

```
def tokenize(s, patt):
    at = 0
    while at < len(s):
        m = patt.match(s, pos=at)
        if not m:
            raise ValueError("Did not expect character at location {}".format(at))
        at = m.end()
        yield m
```

Comment: This may be true for pattern.match() and pattern.search() functions. For the re.match(patn, string, flags=0) function, which doesn't have 'pos' arguments, this explanation holds no good. As @Tim pointed, it may be an useful shortcut which doesn't need programmer to use '^'.

Comment: @mhr: It would be inconsistent if the match method was missing at the module level though